# VS Code: emmet wrap with abbreviation on Blade file

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, laravel-blade, emmet

I'm trying to use the Emmet's "wrap with abbreviation" feature in VS Code in a Blade file, but it doesn't work.
I've tried with cmd+shift+a shortcut and by the cmd+shift+p > wrap with abbreviation command, but nothing happens.
I've no problem using it in .html, .php file, but with file extension `.blade.php` and Laravel Blade as active language it doesn't wrap html code.
Is that a bug, or there is a way to activate the "wrap" for this language?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this in your settings (it's working for me):

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "php": "html",
    "blade": "html"
},
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "php": "html",
    "blade": "html"
}
```

Comment: Is "emmet.syntaxProfiles" field needed? It works well with only includeLanguages settings

Comment: Yes probably not, I wasn't sure which one was working